# How to select embedded property in mongo document

Tags: mongodb

I have a collection with document format shown below.

```
{customerID:1, accDetails:{accType:"saving",balance:100000}}
```

I want to select customerId and balance in mongo powershell. format of output should be like below.

```
{customerID:1,balance:100000}
```

I used below query

```
db.<collectionName>.find({},{_id:0,customerID:1,"accDetails.balance":1})
```

but this query return data in this format

```
{customerID:1, accDetails:{balance:100000}}
```

How to get output in desired format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `aggregate-project`, you can do this

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$project": {
      "customerID": 1,
      "balance": "$accDetails.balance",
      "_id": 0
    }
  }
])
```

[play-mongo](https://mongoplayground.net/p/kNrQkcn5WXY)